# Website not working in https but working fine in http

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I recently launched my website, when it was http it was working fine. Then I used certbot to convert HTTP to https and redirect all HTTP to https, it is also working but https website is not loading now.
Redirection from HTTP to https is fine but website not opening.
May be an issue of .htaccess

Here is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.ico|\.woff|\.woff2|\.svg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|fonts|assets|installer)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Most likely you need to setup a vhost(if using apache) or configure a server file(if using nginx). All traffic hitting port 80 should be redirect to port 443. You can't do that with a htaccess file since the traffic has already reached your app making a viable redirect impossible.

Comment: Explain what _exactly_ _“but website not opening”_ actually means.

Comment: please check the php version of the server

Comment: Can you show us a screen cap that demonstrate how "https website is not loading now"?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.